# Why can only some functions use variables declared outside of the function?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I have this code:

```
def r():
    i += 1
    return i

def f():
    return x*a

i = 0

a=2 
x=3

print f()
print r()
```

I get this error for `r()`, but not for `f()`:

```
~$ python ~/dev/python/inf1100/test.py 
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marius/dev/python/inf1100/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print r()
  File "/home/marius/dev/python/inf1100/test.py", line 2, in r
    i += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Why can `f()` use variables defined outside of the function, whilst `r()` cannot?

Comment: When you do assignment in a function then you creates a *new* object in local namespace, otherwise you are using variable from global namespace.

Comment: Note that 99% of the time, if you want to write to a global variable, you're doing it wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `r` *reassigns* the global variable `i`.  `f` on the other hand just uses it.  Remember that `i += 1` is the same as `i = i + 1`.

Unless you explicitly tell it otherwise, Python treats all variables used within a function as being local.  Furthermore, since there is no variable `i` defined within the local scope of `r`, it throws the error.

If you want to reassign a global variable within a function, you have to put:

```
global var
```

at the top of your function to explicitly declare `var` to be global.

So, to make `r` work, it should be rewritten to this:

```
def r():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to point out that most of the time, this:

```
x = 1

def f():
    global x
    x += 1

f()
```

is bad practice, and you want to use parameters instead:

```
x = 1

def f(a_number):
    return a_number + 1

x = f(x)
```

Also, here:

```
def r():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i
```

`return i` is redundant, the variable is increased by the calling of the function.

Also [this](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value) part of the Python FAQ is relevant and useful.

Answer (score 3):

This piece:

```
def r():
    i += 1
    return i
```

not only *uses* global variables, but also tries to *modify* them (or more accurately: assign different value to global variable `i`).

To make it work, you can just declare this variable as global:

```
def r():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i
```

Answer (score 1):

In `r` you are shadowing your global `i`. Since it is not assigned before you attempt to add to it, you get an error.

A possible solution is to use `global i` in the `r` function like so

```
def r():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign into a variable, python will consider the variable local and won't bother looking for a global variable of the same name. Use `global` as suggested in other answers.